# Python mongodb/motor "'ObjectId' object is not iterable" error while trying to find item in collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I know that there are similar questions, but I've tried everything that was advised and still getting an error. I'm trying to fetch item from mongo collection by id, converting string to an ObjectId, like that:

```
from bson import ObjectId


async def get_single_template(db, template_id):
    template = await db.templates.find_one({ '_id': ObjectId(template_id) })
    return template
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
ValueError: [TypeError("'ObjectId' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

"template_id" is a valid string, like "601401887ecf2f6153bbaaad". ObjectId created from it - too. It fails only to work inside `find_one()` method. When I'm using `find()` with that id it works well. I've tried `from bson.objectid import ObjectId` too - no difference. I'm using `motor` library to access mongo. Is there something that I'm missing?

P.S. Links to the corresponding docs:

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#querying-by-objectid

Though I'm using `motor` async library, I can't find direct examples in it's docs. Basically, it wraps `pymongo`. I can only find examples in other's source code.

Comment: What does pymongo documentation say is the correct usage?

Comment: It says to do it the way I'm doing - convert string to ObjectId...

Comment: Add a link to the documentation to your question and quote the relevant parts.

Comment: I've updated my question with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI issues with MongoDB - TypeError: 'ObjectId' object is not iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467630/fastapi-issues-inserting-into-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks for the answer) I've found out the real problem and wrote about it below, just didn't have enough rep to accept it at the time. That's right, my problem was not in the way I've tried to query data, but in the way I've tried to return it - I've forgotten to convert ObjectId to string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've found out what caused that issue. The problem was not in the way I've tried to query data, but in the way I've tried to return it. I've forgotten to convert ObjectId to string in the entity that I've retrieved from database and tried to return it 'as is'. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem as well while using **Python motor for Mongodb**. In your `app.collection.find_one(...)`, add `{'_id': 0}` along with the dictionary which has the value you want to search for.

So it should be like this:

```
await app.collection.find_one({"value": val},{'_id': 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

After long research i find one solution work for me

I try many ways let's discuss with you one of them

```
DATABASE_URL = mongodb://localhost:portname/yourdbname
client = mongo_client.MongoClient(
  settings.DATABASE_URL#, ServerSelectionTimeoutMS=5000
)
db = client[settings.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE]
Post = db.post

@router.get('/')
async def posts(user_id: str = Depends(oauth2.require_user)):
list = []
for i in Post.find():
    list.append(i)
print("list", list)
return {'status': 'success', "list":  list}
```

Everything work on print but when i return the response then show me error that mentioned in post i solve this error by doing this
serialize ObjectId with native fastApi methods

at top of my file i just import

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pydantic
pydantic.json.ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId]=str
```

Note:
I am not expert of fastapi with MongoDB i just start learning last 5 days ago about fastapi and start learning mongoDb last 2 days ago. if you have any better practice then let me know
i also trying to serialize data but on that case also not work so try this way
thank you

this comment help me from github

```
https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1515#issuecomment-782838556
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think that's better than manually convert in every method)