# FastAPI issues with MongoDB - TypeError: 'ObjectId' object is not iterable

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I am having some issues inserting into MongoDB via FastAPI.

The below code works as expected. Notice how the `response` variable has not been used in `response_to_mongo()`.

The `model` is an sklearn ElasticNet model.

```py
app = FastAPI()


def response_to_mongo(r: dict):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://mongo:27017")
    db = client["models"]
    model_collection = db["example-model"]
    model_collection.insert_one(r)


@app.post("/predict")
async def predict_model(features: List[float]):

    prediction = model.predict(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [features],
            columns=model.feature_names_in_,
        )
    )

    response = {"predictions": prediction.tolist()}
    response_to_mongo(
        {"predictions": prediction.tolist()},
    )
    return response
```

However when I write `predict_model()` like this and pass the `response` variable to `response_to_mongo()`:

```py
@app.post("/predict")
async def predict_model(features: List[float]):

    prediction = model.predict(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [features],
            columns=model.feature_names_in_,
        )
    )

    response = {"predictions": prediction.tolist()}
    response_to_mongo(
        response,
    )
    return response
```

I get an error stating that:

```
TypeError: 'ObjectId' object is not iterable
```

From my reading, it seems that this is due to BSON/JSON issues between FastAPI and Mongo. However, why does it work in the first case when I do not use a variable? Is this due to the asynchronous nature of FastAPI?

Comment: While it seems like a stretch, does `ObjectId` gets populated inside the response object when sent to `insert_one`? If that is the case, your first example ends up with it being inserted in a throw away dict, while in the second example it gets inserted into a dict you're still referencing.

Comment: @MatsLindh I wouldn't think thats the case because the `response` object is not being changed in-place

Comment: Sounds like that's exactly what's happening based on the answer below :-)

Comment: Happy to be proven wrong! Thanks a lot for your answer :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document):

> When a document is inserted a special key, `"_id"`, is automatically
> added if the document doesn’t already contain an `"_id"` key. The value
> of `"_id"` must be unique across the collection. [`insert_one()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) returns an
> instance of [InsertOneResult](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult). For more information on "_id", see the
> [documentation on _id](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs).

Thus, in the second case of the example you provided, when you pass the dictionary to the `insert_one()` function, Pymongo will add to your dictionary the unique identifier (i.e., `ObjectId`) necessary to retrieve the data from the database; and hence, when returning the response from the endpoint, the `ObjectId` fails getting serialized—since, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) in detail, FastAPI, by default, will automatically convert that return value into JSON-compatible data using the [`jsonable_encoder`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/) (to ensure that objects that are not serializable are converted to a `str`), and then return a [`JSONResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#jsonresponse), which uses the standard `json` library to serialise the data.

### Solution 1

Use the approach demonstrated [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1515#issuecomment-782835977), by having the `ObjectId` converted to `str` by default, and hence, you can return the `response` as usual inside your endpoint.

```py
# place these at the top of your .py file
import pydantic
from bson import ObjectId
pydantic.json.ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId]=str

return response # as usual
```

### Solution 2

Dump the loaded `BSON` to valid `JSON` string and then reload it as `dict`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405626) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024423).

```py
from bson import json_util
import json

response = json.loads(json_util.dumps(response))
return response
```

### Solution 3

Define a custom [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16586277), to convert the `ObjectId` into `str`:

```py
import json
from bson import ObjectId

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, ObjectId):
            return str(o)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)


response = JSONEncoder().encode(response)
return response
```

### Solution 4

You can have a separate output model **without** the 'ObjectId' (`_id`) field, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#add-an-output-model). You can declare the model used for the response with the parameter `response_model` in the decorator of your endpoint. Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ResponseBody(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


@app.get('/', response_model=ResponseBody)
def main():
    # response sample
    response = {'_id': ObjectId('53ad61aa06998f07cee687c3'), 'name': 'John', 'age': '25'}
    return response
```

### Solution 5

Remove the `"_id"` entry from the `response` dictionary before returning it (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary) on how to remove a key from a `dict`):

```py
response.pop('_id', None)
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 4, from Chris's excellent answer, can also be accomplished with [function output type hints](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/). Thus:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ResponseBody(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int


@app.get('/')
def example() -> ResponseBody:
    # you'd need to await this if you were using Motor (the Async MongoDB Driver)
    return db.my_collection.find_one(...)
```