# FastApi how to add field in object

Tags: mongodb, fastapi

I have an api like this

```
@router.post("/create-restaurant")
async def create_user(user: user_dependency, data: Restaurant, db: Database = db_dependency):
    print("hitt")
    if user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code= 401, detail='Authentication failed')
    restaurant_data = data.model_dump()
    restaurant_data["user_id"] = user.get("id")
    result = db['restaurant_collection'].insert_one(restaurant_data)
    restaurant_data["id"] = str(result.inserted_id)

    return {"data": restaurant_data}
```

All is working fine I just need to add created_id in restaurant_data. The ID Mongodb return is in string I have try to convert as well but its showing error

```
  data = dict(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^
  TypeError: 'ObjectId' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71468967/17865804) answer your question?